# Confused about the difference between Polymer attribute reflection and two way databinding

Tags: polymer

I am trying to make a polymer element that authenticates users against an SMF forum.  I want the element to expose a "user" property which will initially be an empty object `{}` but if/when the element has made an ajax request and is able to authenticate the user, this object will contain details about the user (and an authentication token) for use in the rest of the application.  The rest of the application is in the content section of the element, and will only be displayed when authetication has happened.

So the application is structured like this

```
<smf-auth login="login/url", fail="fail/url", splash="initial/splash/img" user>
rest of application which will need access to user
</smf-auth>
```

I have published user with reflective properties, and set its initial value to `{}`.  However when I run unit tests, I run javascript to get the element (as a javascript variable) and look at el.user and it has the value "" (ie blank string). I tried altering the code to initialise user as something more complex, but I still get a blank string.

Here is the element definition (with my more complex user)

```
<polymer-element name="smf-auth" attributes="login fail splash">
  <template>
    <core-ajax id="req" url="{{login}}" handleAs="json" on-core-response="{{handleResponse}}"></core-ajax>
    <img id="splash" src="{{splash}}"/>
    <template if="{{autheticated}}">
      <content></content>
    </template>

  </template>

  <script>
  Polymer('smf-auth',{
    publish:{
      user:{
        value:{token:{},uid:0,name:''},
        reflect:true
      }
    },
    created:function(){
      this.authenticated = false;
    },
    attached:function(){
      this.$.req.go();
    },
    handleResponse:function(response){
      //TODO decide what the response is
    }
  });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

So how should I declare and use the "user" property so that the content of the element (more polymer elements) has access to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify a data binding to a user property when you instantiate the *smf-auth* element. Then you can access this property inside the element's body:

```
<smf-auth user="{{user}}" ...>
  Hello {{user.name}}!
</smf-auth>
```

This assumes that your *smf-auth* element is itself inside a Polymer element. Otherwise you need an [auto-binding template element](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#autobinding).

If your element hierarchy is deep and you need the *user* object in an element at the bottom, it can be a problem to pass the *user* property down the hierarchy. In this case another option might be to use [core-signals](http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/communication.html#using-ltcore-signalsgt) and send an event when the user has logged in. Inner elements can then listen for this event and fetch the *user* object from the event details.

Comment: As I see it at the moment (although that may change) smf-auth is the top most polymer element, but the first child will be a another polymer element `<football-manager>` which will then use core-pages to manage the rest of the appplication for authenticated users.

Comment: Although `<smf-auth>` is at the top level, just adding the brackets as per this example exposes the property to javascript. so I can do something like `var el = document.querySelector('smf-auth'); var user =el.user;` in my unit test script to get at the user object and check it is the expected value.